# Bootstrap - Full height row inside column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i would like to have a full height content on the page with off canvas menu.
Example of my code is [here](http://www.bootply.com/hlvM9JGpOC).

My problem is related to the row inside main area. I want it to be the same height as off canvas menu.

Is it possibe? How can I obtain such effect?

Best regards,
Tomasz

Answer (score 0):

A rows height is based on the content you place into it. You can alternatively create your own class in your CSS that sets the height of that row to a desired height. But may become unresponsive as the viewport changes. So *if* that's the case, you will then need to write custom media queries in your CSS to change the height based on viewport size.

Comment: In my case I want to make it "full screen" layout - it mean that on large screans should fullfil the screen but on smaller be just the same height as the off canvas menu. I tried to use in css min-height:100% for html, body and this row but not working in my case, don't know why.